# Proof of something like a Deduction Theorem in Strong K3 Logic.

Tags: logic

Does anyone know if there is a proof of something like a Deduction Theorem in Strong K3 Logic? I am only interested in one direction of the usual biconditional; that is:
{X,A}⊨B ⇒ {X}⊨(A→B)

If there are any articles/chapters, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe useful : [Introduction to Many-Valued Logics](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225052706/http://www.wv.inf.tu-dresden.de/Teaching/SS-2011/mvl/mval.HANDOUT2.pdf) (2011).

Comment: It does not hold for $\text L_3$; see Bergmann, page 114.

Comment: For Kleene's logic, it has to hold, doesn't it? Avron states in his *Proof theory for natural 3-valued logics* that augmentation of $L_3$ with a deduction theorem gives us $K_3$.